# how to implement predictive text functionality inside the text field or text view In Android java so the next word will populate as placeword

Tags: java, android, development-environment

I need to implement the functionality same as G-mail text field , where if. the user is typing, "hi how are" then the "you" is auto populating inside the text field as placeholder , and if I click on you it is taking it as input. how I can achieve this in Android java. this behaviour also known as predictive text. In IOS there is property of text field like textField.InlinePredictiveText = .yes then the text field will give the predictive text. is there any way to implement this kind of behaviour in android using java.

Comment: To implement this feature, you'll require an AutoCompleteTextView, a TextChange listener, and a list containing your suggested words.